# How to configure teamcity build agent to use include files on system?

Tags: c++, teamcity

I've a project that uses boost headers/libraries for which I would like to create a build configuration for a team city build agent (TeamCity 10.0.2 / Windows 10 / Visual studio 2015). The boost headers/libraries are not part of the project (that is boost is not in git). Instead the boost headers/libraries on the development machines are located relative to the project files (for example $(SolutionDir)........\boost_1_59_0).

The build with the build agent fails because the boost header files can't be found. To resolve this I've tried to:

- use a fixed location (for example C:\boost_1_59_0) and put boost on the same location on the machine where the build agent runs but that doesn't help.
- creating an environment variable INCLUDE and set it to to the location of boost. It shows up in the environment variables of the build agent in the team city web interface.
- copying boost to the build agents work directory doesn't work because the build agent removes the directory.
- setting the build agent/teamcity webserver to run as a non "local system" account.

How can the build agent be configured so that it knows where to find the boost libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your build configuration create a **new build step** before `sln` build which copies boost headers into proper folder. Use [*Command Line Runner*](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Command+Line) together with `xcopy` command to do this.

Command line can use source checkout directory:

```
xcopy /Y /E "E:\local_boost_install_folder" "%system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir%\src\boost_1_59_0"
```

One more approach is to set script Working Directory to `%system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir%\src\` and create directory link:

```
mklink /D boost_1_59_0 "E:\local_boost_install_folder"
```

Comment: Interesting suggestion but I don't think this is preferable because a) the "proper folder" has to be a subfolder of the project (otherwise it gets deleted) and b) the boost libraries are quite large. Copying them would add at least 5 minutes to the build.

Comment: @boojum Right. But you could create a `mklink` instead of complete boost copy.

Comment: @boojum I've updated the answer. In your scripts you could use lots of internal TeamCity variables, so it's not a problem to configure the "proper folder". As for myself, I always use `%system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir%` as a root folder for further file manipulation

Comment: Excellent the symbolic link works. Thanks for your help.